# A second try at restricting searches in mySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am really balls confused here. I have no idea what I'm doing, but, I'm trying to restrict searches based on networks being either private or public.

This code does not work, but, I'm trying to figure out how to make this work. How do I make private networks only appear to people in that network????????????????

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM requests ORDER BY dateposted DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    $network = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM network");

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($network)) {
        $display = false;
        $pos = strpos($row['network'], $search);
        if ($row2['visible'] == "public" and $search == "Global") {
            $display = true;
        } else          
        if ($pos == true and 
        ($row2['visible'] == "public" or $row2['username'] == $username)) {
            $display = true;
        } else
        if  ($row2['visible'] == "private") {
            $display = false;
        }
    }
        echo $display;
        if ($display == true){
            echo "<div id='".$row["id"]."' class='item'>";
            echo '<div style="width: 75%;">';
            echo "<h4 style='display: inline;'>".$row["user"]." requests:</h4><br/>";
            echo "<h2 style='display: inline;'>".$row["title"]."  </h2>";
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<h3 id="button" style="border-radius: 10px; padding: 4px; color: white; float: right; position: relative; top: -50px; border: 2px solid grey; background-color: #C0504D;">Apply</h2>';
            echo "</div>";
        }
}
```

The network schema:

```
network text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
username    text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
visible text    utf8_general_ci     No
```

The requests schema:

```
id  int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
user    text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
title   text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
description text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
picture text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
price   text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
premium datetime            No                                  
type    text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
network text    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
dateposted  datetime            No
```

Comment: I can't spot an obvious error, however check what you are evaluating in strpos($row['network'], $search) in case you are getting a true result when you expect false (or vice versa). It's worth noting (although it doesn't _seem_ to apply in this case) that strpos can give unexpected results if not using exact comparisons (=== or !==) because a returned 0 can be evaluated as 'false' when it is really a 'true' result for a string found at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit late here, so I will try to better write this answer.

You need to print all public networks, and only private networks related to the user. Also, if I understood, your search can be "Global" or have a part name of a network, correct?

So your query can be something like this:

```
if( $search == "Global" ) {
  $sql = "select n.*
               , r.* 
            from network n
           inner join request r on n.network = r.network
           where  n.network = 'public' 
              or (n.network = 'private' 
             and  n.username = '".$username."')";
} else {
  $sql = "select n.*
               , r.* 
              from network n
             inner join request r on n.network = r.network
             where  n.network = 'public' 
                or (n.network = 'private' 
               and  n.username = '".$username."')
               and n.network like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'";
}
```

The `like` here means "select me all data where the network name contains the content of search. You can see more examples and explanations [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) and in the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: So wait, what is network n? I don't understand. Does the n. mean I can select from multiple tables at once?

Comment: No, n in this case is the alias for the table.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay, so if I do that query, how would I filter private networks?

Comment: See fred2 comment. You can still filtering by the `$search` but this will simplify your if statement because you will have to test only the name of network against your search.

Comment: Also, what can the user input in the search? Isn't the case of using `LIKE` in your sql query?

Comment: What is LIKE, I'm not sure precisely what you mean. So let's say:

$query2 = select *
  from network n
 where n.visible = 'public'
    or (n.visible = 'private'
   and  n.username = $username)); And then I would just do the same if statement. Could you write out exactly what I should do. I'm still really lost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8563/discussion-between-ccates-and-sergio-michels)

Comment: @CCates sorry, it's late and i'm going :) See if my edit helps you.

Comment: Okay I see. So from there I just do the check if it's private or public?